# How to get access token and access secret after getting client id and and client secret on LinkedIn using python?

Tags: api, oauth, authorization, python-3.5, linkedin-api

I have created an API application in linkedIn, so I got client-id and client-secret key. I am however not able to get access token and secret key from LinkedIn.

I have used the below python code to do the job. Everything works well and I get the 'authorization_url', but when I paste it in my browser I get error: "invalid redirect_uri. This value must match a URL registered with the API Key."

*** Note that at the moment the "Authorized Redirect URLs" section in my application is blank and my question is what I should put there? I understand that it should be the same as what I feed in OAuth2Session function (instead of "arbitrary_url" such as 'http://127.0.0.1') in my below code. But have no clue on where to get this url?

[Snapshot of my authorization_url page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AGuhf.jpg)

*** To clarify on what I exactly do step by step:
1) add a url in "Authorized Redirect URLs" textbox in my API application and click on "Add".
2) Then I replace "arbitrary_url" in my code with exactly the same url.
3) Continue to run my code to get the "redirect_response".
4) Try the "redirect_response" in my browser; So far I always got the error: "invalid redirect_uri. This value must match a URL registered with the API Key."

Would appreciate any help on this.

```
# Import packages
from requests_oauthlib import OAuth2Session
from requests_oauthlib.compliance_fixes import linkedin_compliance_fix

# Credentials you get from registering a new application
client_id = '<my client id>'; client_secret = '<my client secret>'

# Redirect user to LinkedIn for authorization
linkedin = OAuth2Session(client_id, redirect_uri='<arbitrary_url>')
linkedin = linkedin_compliance_fix(linkedin)
authorization_url, state = linkedin.authorization_url('https://www.linkedin.com/uas/oauth2/authorization')
print(authorization_url)
```

Finally I got my mistake in the first phase! What I was missing was that I needed to click on "update" after clicking "Add" in my application to get that addition be actually performed!
**However, still haven't got the client id and and client secret, as I get error after authorization!**

Comment: You have set `redirect_uri='http://127.0.0.1'` as redirect url. When you created your API application what is the redirect url that you provided? You should give the same url here to get correct auth_url.

Comment: Many thanks @Venkatesh for your time! As mentioned, I have only got client-id and client-secret from my application in https://www.linkedin.com/developer/ and don't know what to add to "Authorized Redirect URLs" section in my application. I can see in the docs that it should be in this format: "https://www.example.com/auth/linkedin". Any idea or suggestion on what url should I add there? How can I get that url?

Comment: Generally you can add anything for example: `https://www.example.com/auth/linkedin`. If you don't know what to give give something that works for example `http://localhost:8080`. Have something running there so that you know if you were able to get there successfully after authentication. In your python code you should have same value. You can have multiple redirect urls in any Oauth application.

Comment: Thanks again. I've tried both your provided examples as well as a third one as: "https://localhost:8080/auth/linkedin". None of them worked and I still receive error as : "invalid redirect_uri. This value must match a URL registered with the API Key".

Comment: Can you share your linkedIn application's configured redirect urls screenshot as described here [link](https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/oauth2) ? I believe you are giving the same redirect url configured in the application.  Also please paste your final `authorization_url` by removing client_id and client_secret.

Comment: Added the snapshot to the question, but not sure if it is done alright. The final authorization_url is (it actually does not include my client_secret!):  https://www.linkedin.com/uas/oauth2/authorization?response_type=code&client_id=MY_CLIENT_ID&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.example.com%2Fauth%2Flinkedin&state=ayDq6AnmfRoVNQrPOH3YSXIWpuQAfq

Comment: Your authorized redirect url is empty, It should be `https://www.example.com/auth/linkedin` which is what you are getting in auth_url. Please update it.

Comment: I have already tried many options, none of them worked. The last one as you advised, is that I added the [link](https://www.example.com/auth/linkedin) in the "Authorized Redirect URLs" section of my application (as shown in the updated snapshot in the question) and re-ran the code and got this new authorization_url, still it gives me the same error. My updated authorization_url is: [link](https://www.linkedin.com/uas/oauth2/authorization?response_type=code&client_id=MY_CLIENT_ID&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.example.com%2Fauth%2Flinkedin&state=xbt0gRdGROIOeqI9nAwilGA44r0G7e)

Comment: Your error is due to the redirect_url mismatch. Now that you fixed the redirect url in the application. It should not throw this error. Can you paste the error.

Comment: Many Thanks @VenkateshMarepalli! Finally I got my mistake! What I was missing was that I needed to click on "update" after clicking "Add" in my application to get that addition be actually performed! Now I get prompted for my personal linkedin username and password. but, when I put there and click on "Allow access", I get error. What do you advise on this? This site can’t be reached: The webpage at https://www.example.com/auth/linkedin?code=MY_CODE&state=ArjkCcvn8hm84pL7vqDJNt62iw81hB#! might be temporarily down or it may have moved permanently to a new web address.
ERR_INVALID_RESPONSE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please refer to samples https://github.com/ozgur/python-linkedin. I see that you are missing to match redirect_url in your code. And more samples and explanation here http://requests-oauthlib.readthedocs.io/en/latest/examples/linkedin.html

Comment: Many Thanks @VenkateshMarepalli! Finally I passed this stage however have not got the access token and access key yet. Now I get prompted for my personal linkedin username and password. but, when I put there and click on "Allow access", I get error. This site can’t be reached: The webpage at https://www.example.com/auth/linkedin?code=MY_CODE&state=xbt0gRdGROIOeqI9nAwilGA44r0G7e#! might be temporarily down or it may have moved permanently to a new web address. ERR_INVALID_RESPONSE. What would you advise on this?

Comment: I guess you gave a dummy redirect url, test it with a working url.

Comment: Not sure if I totally understood! I gave [this redirect url](https://www.example.com/auth/linkedin) as you suggested. If this is a dummy one, what should I put there as a **working url**?

Comment: Redirect to something which works. localhost:8080 or something. www.google.com, anything which works.